Framing of HStack to fit parent view size with padding
I have a view which is HStack of images with a horizontal padding. I want this HStack to fit in the parent view and fill it's width (along with padding). I have set a background color of yellow after setting the padding. Problem is the background is not visible on the screen. I am using .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal) and honestly I don't exactly know how it works as it gives unpredictable results sometimes, so I have been experimenting putting this modifier in various places.
My question is how do I modify this code so that the entire HStack with padding fills the parent view width?

import SwiftUI
import UIKit

extension UIImage {
    class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize=CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: size))
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image!
    }
}

struct ThumbImage: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var image:UIImage
}

struct TestHStack: View {
    @State var images:[ThumbImage] = []
    @State var numImages:Int = 15
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(images) { thumbImage in
                    Image(uiImage: thumbImage.image)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                        .clipped()
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            
        }
        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
        .onGeometryChange(for: CGFloat.self, of: { proxy in
            proxy.size.width
        }, action: { newValue in
            numImages = Int((newValue)/50)
            print("numImages = \(numImages), \(newValue)")
        })
        .onAppear(perform: {
            print("On Appear")
            generateThumbs()
        })
        .onChange(of: numImages, { oldValue, newValue in
            print("On Change")
            generateThumbs()
            
        })
    }
    
    func generateThumbs() {
        var thumbs:[ThumbImage] = []
        var altColor:Color = .red
        for _ in 0..<numImages {
            thumbs.append(imageFromColor(altColor))
            altColor = altColor == .red ? .blue : .red
        }
        
        images = thumbs
    }
    func imageFromColor(_ color:Color) -> ThumbImage {
        let uiColor = UIColor(color)
        let uiImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: uiColor, size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
        
        return ThumbImage(image: uiImage)
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    TestHStack()
}


Can you show what your desired result is, as an image? I find your description hard to understand.

I just want HStack with padding (yellow background) to fill the screen. Currently, padding looks to be outside the bounds of screen and only the HStack fills the screen.

I cannot reproduce that on iPhone 16 Pro Max, iPhone 15, or 13-inch iPad. But it seems like you should be doing proxy.size.width - 40 instead of proxy.size.width. You should subtract the padding from the total width of the color images.

@Sweeper That's doable and it works, but it's possible the number of Images generated may not fill the entire screen. what I would ideally want is to have enough images to fill the entire screen along with padding, and then clip the HStack on the right side if the HStack width is more than screen width. Is that possible?
